# Javascript issue in Inventory Transfers and Receipts

Tags: acumatica

i have added a new unbound field to display image of Inventory Item in Transaction Details tab, then to set the fixed height of the image I have added some javascript, but after adding javascript the screen is not populating any default values into like RefNbr and Date, Below is the javascript code am using. The same javascript code is working on my custom screen.

```
<px:PXJavaScript runat="server" ID="CstJavaScript1" Script="var css = &#39;.GridRow > img { width: 100%; height: 40px; }&#39;, head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;head&#39;)[0], style = document.createElement(&#39;style&#39;); style.type = &#39;text/css&#39;; if (style.styleSheet){   style.styleSheet.cssText = css; } else { style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css)); }  head.appendChild(style);" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier I have added Javascript inside the tab item, but now I moved out of the Tab when it was working without issues.

```
</px:PXTab>
<px:PXJavaScript runat="server" ID="CstJavaScript1" Script="var css = &#39;.GridRow > img { width: 100%; height: 40px; }&#39;, head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;head&#39;)[0], style = document.createElement(&#39;style&#39;); style.type = &#39;text/css&#39;; if (style.styleSheet){   style.styleSheet.cssText = css; } else { style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css)); }  head.appendChild(style);" />
```